# Linux-compatible USB temperature & humidity logger

Tags: usb, linux

does anyone have any experience of using USB temperature & humidity sensors under Linux? I suspect we may have a damp problem and I want to assess the level of humidity in various rooms in my house over 24-48h so I can work out if there's a real problem.

- Data analysis isn't a problem as long as I can load it up into a pandas DataFrame in Python
- I'm not looking for something that needs to be plugged into a running computer but that will record on battery power and then upload logged data when plugged in
- The ideal would be something available in the UK

So, for example, I've found [this](https://www.omega.co.uk/pptst/OM-140-SERIES.html), which claims:

> "After a data log has been captured and stored, it can be uploaded as a .txt file to any PC running the Windows® XP/7 or 8 operating system after plugging the data logger into one of the computer's USB ports"

But there's no indication of the actual upload mechanism and whether it requires a special client that's Windows-only or whether it just uses generic USB mass storage. I could use wine, but don't know if their software would be compatible.

Can anyone recommend a decent quality thermometer/hygrometer that works well (or has know workarounds) under Linux?

Comment: Judging from the fact they provide a "mini-disc" with drivers and dedicated software Id bet it wont work. Unless it's a usb serial (with standard drivers) and you will be able to launch that software under wine.

Answer (score 1):

I ordered a EasyLog EL-SIE-1+ from Lascar Electronics and all the features worked with Linux (Tested on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS).

- Product Page = https://www.lascarelectronics.com/easylog-el-sie-1plus
- Datasheet =
  https://www.lascarelectronics.com/media/8411/easylog-data-logger-el-sie-1plus-iss4_11-22.pdf

Lascar also offers similar loggers that measure humidity + temperature in a single device (EL-SIE-2+).  I haven't personally tested this variant.

All configuration and data extraction is done through your web browser connecting locally to the device via an included USB cable.  No special software, internet connection, or registration is required.  After plugging the device into your computer, navigate to http://EasyLog.local in your web browser to configure the device or download stored data.  You can download a raw CSV of your data or view a pretty graph from the web UI.

The device does have more thermal inertia than I'd like.  I did an experiment where I put it in my freezer (3F) and let it warm up in the ambient air of my house (77F)

- It took 8 minutes to go from 3F to 50F (77 ambient)
- It took 16 minutes to go from 3F to 60F (77 ambient)
- It took 27 minutes to go from 3F to 70F (77 ambient)
- It took 68 minutes to go from 3F to 77F (77 ambient)

Also, my device heated up significantly when plugged in via USB, displaying a temperature of 86F when the ambient temperature was 77F.  It will cool back down to ambient when unplugged but may take a while.

Despite the above quirks, I'd recommend this logger if your measured temperatures aren't changing rapidly.